# CSS3 and jQuery Transition Flash on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I'm working on a new responsive website and I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out an issue I'm having when testing on iOS devices. I have created a sliding-panel menu reveal (a la the old Facebook app) for mobile and tablet users utilizing CSS3 transitions and then I use jQuery to add/remove a few classes to lock the sliding panel when it is expanded.

The issue that I am having is that when you choose to slide the panel over, everything in that panel briefly flashes white on iOS devices before it begins sliding over. When I close the panel, though, it works great and there is no flash. If I test it on a desktop browser it does not flash on either open or close.

Link to test site: http://staging.michalekbrothersracing.com/css-sliding-panel/

Does anyone have any experience fixing a bug like this? I'd appreciate and help that you could offer. Thank you!

---

UPDATE:

I've messed around with it a little more and I think I've isolated where the flicker is coming from. I'm new to jQuery and at best I'm hacking a bunch of stuff together so this is more than likely my fault. This section of code freezes the sliding panel when it's open and when I don't include it, the panel no longer flashes before it opens. Any idea what might be causing it or ides on a potential remedy?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('#content-container', 'body').addClass('freeze');
                $('#content-container').removeClass('scrollable');
                $('#mobile-nav').scrollTop(0);
            } else {
                $('#content-container', 'body').removeClass('freeze');
                $('#content-container').addClass('scrollable');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can add `transform: translateZ(0);` to the element to get it hardware accelerated, which should remove the flash.

My understanding is that you are taking an element from the CPU rendering layer and moving it to the GPU rendering layer as you apply 3D transforms. As this transition occurs, you get that flash. By adding a 3D transform by default to the element, it lives in the GPU rendering layer (on supported devices / OSes).

Note for iOS you'll need to prefix that `transform` property name with `-webkit-`.

Comment: Thanks, Jasper. I tried this solution, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem. I've updated my original post after doing some more digging and I believe I have isolated the section of code that is causing problems.